# Schema Drift not working as expected Azure DF (Multiple files of 2 different schema formats)

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

[Derived column pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdSEO.jpg)
Objective :
We have two sample datasets with different Schema formats. Our Objective is to load different schema format files present in the source with single pipeline as it is not possible for us to segregate the source files based on their schemas. The data is loaded into a database with structure as attached.
We have created a pipeline in Azure Data factory that connects to the source and loads all the csv present in the source with the derived column transformation.
The source and sink both have Schema drift enabled and column pattern is used in the derived column transformation.

Issue : The pipeline works fine and maps the target column  correctly if only A type or only S type files are present in the source but if both files are mixed then the mapping on the target table is not happening correctly. Schema drift is not working when source has two different source file mixed together.
here is schema format defined with Table structure.

Schema A Format :              Filename,Cost_Type,ResourceType,Group,Subgroup,Description,Pay Class,ResourceName,Date,Hours

Schema B Format :       Filename,Cost_Type,Resource Type,Group,Sub-Group,WBS Name,Activity Name,Resource Name,Date,Hours

Comment: So  the SQL table has all the columns in A type and B type?

Comment: Yes SQL Table will have all the column of A and B like this.

Comment: [Filename] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [CostType] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [ResourceType] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [Group] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [Subgroup] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [Description] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [PayClass] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [ResourceName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [Date] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [Hours] FLOAT  NULL,
 [WBSName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [Activity Name] [nvarchar](max) NULL

Answer (score 3):

Schema drift protects your ETL by automatically handling changes to your source metadata. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-schema-drift

Your use case is different. You are trying to define a single source that has multiple different schema definitions. If you were processing Parquet source files, we could perform an implicit schemaMerge. But since you are processing CSV sources you need an alternative approach.

How many files are you processing on each pipeline execution? Can you instead send the files into the data flow activity one file at a time from a pipeline ForEach?

That approach works because the schema will be discovered on the fly by data flow upon each invocation. It is recommended that when using ForEach with a data flow activity that you minimize parallelization and use a sequential approach, which limits the scalability of this approach.

Answer (score 1):

What @Mark Kromer MSFT said is correct. We can import data from different schema format files via a ForEach activity. According to your screenshot, I guess you are using a csv files as data source.

Based on the above situation,I think we don't need to use data flow. I did an experiment as follows:
I created two csv files in Azure Data Lake gen2 container **test5** and a table in Azure SQL in your format:
[image]
Finally I imported the two different schema csv files into a SQL table.
[image]

**In ADF:**

1. We can use `Child Items` at Get Metadata1 activity to get the file list.
   [image]
2. Then we can traverse the file list at ForEach1 activity.
   [image]
3. In the ForEach activity1, we can use Get Metadata2 to get the file structure(column name).
   [image]
   The file structure is as follows and the dataset is **DelimitedText45** we will use this dataset next:
   [image]
   On the file path option of the source data, we need to key in `@item().name`.
   [image]
4. In the If Condition activity, we can use `@equals(activity('Get Metadata2').output.structure[5].name,'Description')` to determine the type of file.
   [image]
5. In the true condition, I defined a Copy activity1 and created a new dataset of the **test5** container.
   [image]

And we need to **import schemas** and set the **mapping**.
[image]

5. In the false condition, the steps are the same. I defined a Copy activity2.
   [image]
   We can use the same dataset, but we need to  **import schemas** and set the **mapping** again.
   [image]
6. Then we can run debug, the data will be correctly imported into the sql table.

Comment: Thank you so much for your great effort on this ,however the name of the csv can not be used to distinguish between two type of schema formats , It one of the column say Cost type which can be like 'A%' or 'S%'

Comment: You don't need to follow the example from Joseph above. In fact, IMO, it is too complicated. Instead, just use the Data Flow like you had before, but parameterize the Source dataset and send in the name of the file to process from the ForEach. That will make schema drift in data flow work for your use case.

Comment: @Charu Thareja, I've updated my answer,  we can judge the schema based on the column name. I've also tried Mark's answer but got an [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RP5vE.png),maybe I missed something

Comment: Thanks Mark but as i said we can not distinguish the type of type from their names